# How to move the notification badge to the left right next to the UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to move a custom notification badge with the following code. The badge only can go up or down. I am not able to move it left or right. profileBadge is custom UIView. I add the custom badge UIView to an UIButton and then i move it up by -4.0 in y axis. I try to move it to the left using -8.0 in x axis using CGRectFrame but does not move. The UIButton with the badge UIView is added in the top navigation bar.

```
    profileBadge= [[BadgeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 14.0, 14.0)];
    
    profileBadge.font = badgeFont;
    profileBadge.horizontalAlignment = M13BadgeViewHorizontalAlignmentRight;
    profileBadge.verticalAlignment = M13BadgeViewVerticalAlignmentNone;
    profileBadge.badgeBackgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    profileBadge.text = @"";
    profileBadge.hidden = YES;
    [profileBadge setFrame:CGRectMake(-8.0, -4.0, 14.0, 14.0)];
    [profileBadge.superview bringSubviewToFront:profileBadge];
     Button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 14, 0, 8);
    [Button addSubview:profileBadge];
```

I tried using also using profileBadge.layoutMargins but does not move left or right. Any help apprecitated.